# Much needed: well-highlighted JSON log viewer

Tags: json, sublimetext, gedit, winston

Using [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) for node.js logging, I get json log files. A log file in this vein is simply a sequence of (newline delimited) json objects. This is great for log querying and treating logs as first-class data!

However, both `Sublime` and `gedit` (at least the versions of them I'm using on Ubuntu, sublime 2 and gedit 3.6.2), poorly highlight json - they use the same color for keys and values, making any log drilling quite painful and really impossible to go through in any remotely humane manner.

Existing `chrome extensions` for json highlighting aren't helpful here either - they can't handle a collection of json objects and thus fail displaying these log files unless I manually turn them into an array within a synthetic parent object first (thus turning them into a json object). This is tedious in the case of viewing a log file that is still being written to and in general......

Is there any tool that can both swallow json log files as is, and at the same time highlight keys in a different color than values, so that json logs are also friendly to man, not only to machine?? this is a real pain.

Thanks!

Comment: why is not possible to choose the best answer?

Answer (score 29):

Check out the [Neon Color Scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net) and [Github](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme) for Sublime Text. Keys and values are highlighted in different colors, and there are different key colors for different levels.

[image: JSON with Neon]

Full disclosure: I'm the maintainer for this project, but I really think it'll help you out - it certainly helps me when working with multi-leveled JSON files like the one shown above.

Comment: Thanks,this looks helpful, but I kind of like my current highlighting scheme for regular source files. Can it apply only to JSON and keep my other doc types highlighted as they already are??

Comment: @matt - yes, you can. The `.tmTheme` file is pretty organized - just copy the highlighted lines from [here](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/blob/master/Neon.tmTheme#L1055-1268) (1055-1268) and put them in your own theme.

Comment: Is there a way to use the same colors for each of the nested levels, but still have keys and values have different colors?

Comment: @blah238 - I'm not sure what you're asking. Please [open an issue](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/issues/new) and describe exactly what you'd like to see, with a screenshot if possible (you can use Word/OpenOffice with different colored text if you want).

Comment: you can customize this theme here: [link](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/theme/Neon)

Comment: Check out the MonokaiJSON+ Theme I created, I think that is what a lot of people want: http://goo.gl/39ZBnA

Answer (score 22):

If you like the default Monkai Theme, check out MonokaiJSON+ Theme!
It supports strings, dictionaries, arrays and all of these mixed as well!

https://github.com/ColibriApps/MonokaiJsonPlus

[image: Monokai JSON+ Theme]

Comment: Just installed it, Sublime 3, and nothing gets formatted nor highlighted for json documents (Sublime does say "JSON" on the right side of the bottom bar).

Comment: Hm, I am using Sublime 3 also 3083... Please try to set the type CMD+Shift+P -> "Set syntax JSON"

Comment: After installing MonokaiJSON+, you need to change the color scheme: Sublime Text > Preferences > Color Scheme > MonokaiJSON+

Comment: This isn't working for me. It appears MonokaiJSON+ is incompatible after 3.2? https://github.com/ColibriApps/MonokaiJsonPlus/issues/7

Comment: It's broken in Sublime 3.2. https://github.com/ColibriApps/MonokaiJsonPlus/issues/7 You can fix it by https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/rainbow-colors-by-json-object-level-with-any-color-scheme/42968

Comment: BROKEN in subl 3 … package is 5 years old.

Answer (score 5):

I modified original twilight theme to add rules for prettier json. It's a modified version of @MattDMo 's answer, and has the similar different key colors for different levels. You can get it from here

https://github.com/shaunakv1/twilight-tmTheme-better-json-highlight

Here's how JSON looks:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Mixing [Allen Bargui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205455/much-needed-well-highlighted-json-log-viewer/21209775#21209775)'s and [MattDMo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205455/much-needed-well-highlighted-json-log-viewer#comment31961468_21213086)'s answers, you can change the color of the nested keys/values by simply adding more dicts specifying the depth of the code by adding a `meta` after the source.json word.

Locate the theme file by going to *Preferences > Browse Packages*  and then inside the *Color Scheme - Default* folder. Edit it by adding these lines:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Json Keys - 1 deep</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.json meta meta.structure.dictionary.json string.quoted.double.json</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FF0000</string> <!-- your keys color -->
    </dict>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>JSON Values - 1 deep</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.json meta meta.structure.dictionary.json meta.structure.dictionary.value.json string.quoted.double.json</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#00FF00</string> <!-- your custom color -->
    </dict>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Json Keys</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.json meta.structure.dictionary.json string.quoted.double.json</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FF0000</string> <!-- your keys color -->
    </dict>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>JSON Values</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.json meta.structure.dictionary.json meta.structure.dictionary.value.json string.quoted.double.json</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#00FF00</string> <!-- your custom color -->
    </dict>
</dict>
```

It's important to **add the deeper ones BEFORE the rest**, as Sublime will select the first matching occurrence. I guessed adding more `meta` would work for further depths but it actually didn't... But it did the trick for depth 1 at least.

Comment: This highlights anything double quoted, not just the keys

Comment: Actually I you want to highlight all Strings, Dictionaries, Arrays the same at each level, it gets quite complicated, check out MonokaiJSON+ Theme: https://goo.gl/39ZBnA

Answer (score 2):

I developed a command line tool to view json log (see https://github.com/qiangyt/jog). It is just like 'tail -f log-file' but it's for json log.

It's written using GO so it's cross-platform. The binaries are downloadable via https://github.com/qiangyt/jog/releases.

Not document how to configure it very well, but it works properly by default,and I'm happy to get issue report or new feature request

Comment: Based on a description looks quite awesome, I should try that!

Comment: Really appreciated if able to get feedback

Answer (score 0):

looking at a json file in SublimeText, I realised keys and values have different scopes. so it should be very trivial to customize your color scheme and add different color for keys and values.

keys have scope of `source.json meta.structure.dictionary.json string.quoted.double.json`
 while values have `source.json meta.structure.dictionary.json meta.structure.dictionary.value.json string.quoted.double.json`

so if you add this snippet at the bottom of you color scheme rules you should see them in different colors:

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Json Keys</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>source.json meta.structure.dictionary.json string.quoted.double.json</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FF0000</string> <!-- your keys color -->
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>JSON Values</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>source.json meta.structure.dictionary.json meta.structure.dictionary.value.json string.quoted.double.json</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#00FF00</string> <!-- your custom color -->
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: This works but only at the top level. Nested keys/values all get the same color.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually It is not so simple, that's why I created this new MonokaiJson+ Theme: https://goo.gl/39ZBnA

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that https://jsonlog.io/ is a solution that provides great visibility into your application's structured data IO. I'm the developer behind this, but it's a free resource I built to solve this exact issue in my own workflow.

Here's an example of one of the log formats that might help:

[JSONLog Pretty Log View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcbUj.png)

And since it's a live logging-type platform the data displays live as they are sent from your application. It's a great way to get insight into your live/dev application IO.

Comment: Linked tool is offline and no other information is provided to help track it down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visualize winston json log at console you can use  [munia-pretty-json](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/munia-pretty-json)

Your json data (app-log.json)

```
{"time":"2021-06-09T02:50:22Z","level":"info","message":"Log for pretty JSON","module":"init","hostip":"192.168.0.138","pid":123}
{"time":"2021-06-09T03:27:43Z","level":"warn","message":"Here is warning message","module":"send-message","hostip":"192.168.0.138","pid":123}
```

Run the command:

```
munia-pretty-json app-log.json
```

Here is readable output on console:

[image]

You can format the output with the template. The default template is `'{time} {level -c} {message}'`

Using template:

```
munia-pretty-json -t '{module -c} - {level} - {message}' app-log.json
```

Output:
[image]